# How to manage TTL exceeded error in kue module of Redis in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, redis, task-queue, kue

I am working on NodeJS application, in that application I used kue module of Redis to manage queuing to perform tasks.

There is an error "TTL exceeded". Due to this error whole redis tasks queue has been stueyeck and it may not auto start queue as well as not allow to executing other pending tasks in queue.

**As per Kue documentation:**

> Job producers can set an expiry value for the time their job can live in active state, so that if workers didn't reply in timely fashion, Kue will fail it with TTL exceeded error message preventing that job from being stuck in active state and spoiling concurrency.

I don't know how to manage this situation. I post my code, I required help to resolve an issue.

```
"use strict";
const redisConst = require('../../constants/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.json').redis;
const DataConsolidationController = require('../../api/data-consolidation/controller/data-consolidation-controller');
const ContactController = require('../../api/contact/controller/contact-controller');
const GmailController = require('../../api/email/gmail/gmail-controller');
const FileUploadController = require('../../api/file-upload/controller/file-upload-controller');
var fs = require('fs');
var kue = require('kue');
/*
* If you have a huge concurrency in uncompleted jobs,
* turn this feature off and use queue level events for better memory scaling.
*/
var queue = kue.createQueue({
    prefix: 'qt',
    redis: redisConst,
    jobEvents: false,
    removeOnComplete: true
});
var job;
var _io;
var concurrency = 5;

/* queue setting */
queue.on('ready', () => {
    console.info('Queue is ready!');
});

// A job get executed
queue.on('job enqueue', (id, type) => {
    console.log('Job %s got queued', id);
});

// A job get removed
queue.on('job complete', (id, result) => {
    kue.Job.get(id, (err, job) => {
        if (err)
            return;
        job.remove((err) => {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            console.log('Removed completed job #%d', job.id);
        });
    });
});

queue.on("job process", (id, result) => {
    kue.Job.get(id, (err, job) => {
        if (err)
            return;
        console.log("job process is done", job.id);
    });
})

queue.on('error', (err) => {
    // handle connection errors here
    console.error('There was an error in the main queue!');
    console.error(err);
    console.error(err.stack);
});

queue.watchStuckJobs();

process.once('SIGTERM', (sig) => {
    queue.shutdown(5000, (err) => {
        console.log('Kue shutdown: ', err || '');
        process.exit(0);
    });
});


/* workers */
queue.process('import', concurrency, (job, done) => {
    switch (job.data.type) {
        // File upload import
        case 'file-upload-import':
            FileUploadController.csvUploadWithQueueTechifyNew(_io.sockets.connected[job.data.socketId], job.data.filePath, job.data.userId)
                //FileUploadController.csvUploadWithQueue(_io.sockets.connected[job.data.socketId], job.data.filePath, job.data.userId)
                .then(result => {
                    fs.unlinkSync(job.data.filePath);
                    done();
                })
                .then(result => {
                    ContactController.recommendationEngine(null, job.data.userId);
                    done();
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    done(err);
                });
            break;
    }
});

function findJobCount() {
    queue.activeCount((err, count) => {
        if (!err)
            console.log('**** Active: ', count);
    });
    queue.inactiveCount((err, count) => {
        if (!err)
            console.log('**** Inactive:', count);
    });
}

module.exports = class QueueController {
    static init(io) {
        _io = io;
    }

    /* producers */
    static createJob(name, data) {
        if (data.type === 'import-salesforce-data') {
            job = queue.create(name, data)
                .delay(1000)
                .ttl(600000)
                .attempts(1)
                .backoff(true)
                .removeOnComplete(true)
                .save((err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        done(err);
                    } else if (!err) {
                        done();
                    }
                });
        } else {
            job = queue.create(name, data)
                .delay(1000)
                .ttl(120000)
                .attempts(1)
                .backoff(true)
                .removeOnComplete(true);
        }

        job
            .on('start', () => {
                console.log('Job', job.id, 'is now running');
                findJobCount();
            })
            .on('complete', () => {
                console.log('Job', job.id, 'is done');
                findJobCount();
            })
            .on('failed', () => {
                console.log('Job', job.id, 'has failed');
                job.remove();
                findJobCount();
            })
            .on("progress", () => {
                console.log("job", job.id, "is progressing");
            });

        job.save((err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error in adding Job: ' + err);
            } else {
                console.log("Job saved");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TTL exceeded means your job is not getting completed within TTL. **Please check why your job is not getting completed within TTL**??
As per my understaing of your code - In queue.process all data.type is not handled, thus done is never called and job remains in active for long period and eventually ttl expires.

Also you have ttl of 5min and 10 min, thus each job remains active for 5 or 10 min thus not giving chance to other job for long period. **Reduce TTL if possible.**

As you have concurrency of 5 means your all 5 concurrent job is in active and stuck state, thus no other job can be scheduled. **Increase concurrency if possible.**

You can also **use kue-ui-express to get GUI representation** of your jobs and their status.

And also if many jobs is there in kue, waiting to be executed, kue may be spilling some job.